# Finding records whose object contains a String value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find, mongodb-query

I have a collection, the document in it looks like this:

```
{ 
    "person-name" : "Hughart, Ron", 
    "info" : { 
        "birthnotes" : [ "Los Angeles, California, USA" ], 
        "birthdate" : [ "18 June 1961" ], 
        "birthname" : [ "Hughart, Ronald P" ] 
    } 
}
```

I want to find the people who were born in Lisbon. The question is how do I know if a record's field `"info.birthnotes"` contains `"Lisbon"`?

I tried this command:

```
db.collection.find({"info.birthnotes": {"$in": ["Lisbon"]}})
```

but it returns nothing.

Comment: in your example info.birthnotes does not contain "Lisbon"

Answer (score 1):

From inspection, the `"info.birthnotes"` array may look like it has comma separated elements

```
"info.birthnotes" : [ "Los Angeles", "California", "USA" ]
```

yet it has a single string value `"Los Angeles, California, USA"` which is comma separated:

```
"info.birthnotes" : [ "Los Angeles, California, USA" ]
```

You are currently querying it as if it is multi-valued with single sttring values as elements. You need to use a **[`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)** based query to return the documents whose `"info.birthnotes"` array string contains `"Lisbon"` as follows:

```
db.collection.find({ "info.birthnotes": { "$regex": /Lisbon/i } })
```

or if you are using a variable with the **[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** constructor to create a regular expression object you can use in your query:

```
var query = "Lisbon";
var rgx = new RegExp(query, "i");
db.collection.find({"info.birthnotes": rgx})
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to find is by using a regular expression

```
db.collection.find({"info.birthnotes": /.*Lisbon.*/})
```